# Laravel Subquery with Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a MySQL query like this:

```sql
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.nip,
    a.name,
    COUNT(
      (
        SELECT id
        FROM covis_transactions
        WHERE user_id = a.id
      )
    ) AS total_survey
FROM users a
WHERE a.user_role_id = 7
GROUP BY a.id
```

I tried converting it to an Eloquent query but this seems not to work:

```php
DB::table('users as a')
    ->selectRaw("a.id, a.nip, a.name, COUNT(".DB::table('covis_transactions')->where('user_id', 'a.id').") as total_survey")
    ->where('a.user_role_id', 7)
    ->groupBy('a.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: You can explain more about the database scheme and relationship we can easily.... So we Use laravel eloquent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a relationship between your `User` model and the model for the `covis_transactions` table. (I'm gonna call it `CovisTransaction`)

```php
# User.php
public function covis_transactions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CovisTransaction::class);
}
```

Then, you can use `withCount` to get the aggregate count.

```php
User::query()
    ->select('id', 'nip', 'name')
    ->withCount('covis_transactions as total_survey')
    ->where('user_role_id', 7)
    ->groupBy('id')
    ->get();
```

---

- https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many
- https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#aggregating-related-models

Answer (score 0):

You can convert subquery from a builder to a string :

`DB::table('covis_transactions')->where('user_id', 'a.id')`

`DB::table('covis_transactions')->where('user_id', 'a.id')->toSql()`

try it :

```
DB::table('users as a')
            ->selectRaw("a.id, a.nip, a.name, COUNT(" . DB::table('covis_transactions')->where('user_id', 'a.id')->toSql() . ") as total_survey")
            ->where('a.user_role_id', 7)
            ->groupBy('a.id')
            ->get();
```

Or can use `join` then count(`covis_transactions`.`id`)